# ReactJS "Download error or resource isn't a valid image"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

After resorting the folder structure of my project in the console I get this error:

> Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)

I just added some folders in the "src" folder for maintaining components and assets. Is it because of changing the folder structure or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you deleted that image from `public/` folder OR you removed icons: [] from `manifest.json` in `public/`